# Array.prototype.each = function(callback) { for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) callback(this[i]); } - is this ok?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, iteration, prototype

I know it's a matter of taste, but for my taste using for loop each time I want to iterate over array is bad. So I came up with this:

```
Array.prototype.each = function(callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    callback(this[i]);
}
```

Now I can do:

```
[10, 20, 30].each(function(n) { console.log(n/10) })
```

Later I found some tips on the Internet that suggested this approach, but I still wonder if it's free from side effects. It seems very obvious, and that is what worries me :)

I'm not using any library like jQuery or Prototype. I'm coding for Node.js.

Comment: If you're using Node.js, the function is already available!  It's called "forEach", not "each". It's part of JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use `forEach`. It's implemented in most modern browsers, and the shim is provided by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

On node.js, it's implemented (it uses V8, same engine as Chrome), so you don't need a shim.

Its use is something like the following:

```
arr.forEach( function( el ) {
    // play with "el"
} )
```

Also, I suggest you look at the new array methods provided by ES5:

- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
- [Some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Thanks. So - can I use it always instead of for(var i = 0; [...] to iterate over array? Most examples on SO tend to use for loop.

Comment: Yes, you can. Most examples on SO suck :p Also, the `for` loop is *slightly* faster, but `forEach` is just so much better that the *slight* performance loss is worth it.

Answer (score 3):

This does have a pretty big side effect

If we now run the following code

```
a = [10, 20, 30];
for (var i in a) {
    console.log(i + ": " + a[i]);
}
```

And check the console output, we see this:

```
0: 10
1: 20
2: 30
each: function (callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    callback(this[i]);
}
```

Which restricts the type of for loop you can do on an array to

```
a = [10, 20, 30];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    console.log(a[i] + ": " + a[i]);
}
```

Comment: The native `.forEach()` callback function is passed the index as its second parameter. That's one of the reasons to use the real built-in version of the function: some thought went into its design :-)

Comment: I wouldn't feel comfortable looping arrays with `for-in`, even if I *didn't* extend Array.prototype. Besides indices-as-strings and iteration of non-own properties, the semantics of Objects and Arrays JS are already so blurred as to cause confusion, without making the problem worse like this.

Answer (score 1):

From:

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.18
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {

  Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback, thisArg) {

    var T, k;

    if (this === null) {
      throw new TypeError(' this is null or not defined');
    }

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling toObject() passing the
    // |this| value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get() internal
    // method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be toUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If isCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception. 
    // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if (typeof callback !== "function") {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }

    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let
    // T be undefined.
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = thisArg;
    }

    // 6. Let k be 0
    k = 0;

    // 7. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {

      var kValue;

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //    This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty
      //    internal method of O with argument Pk.
      //    This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal
        // method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[k];

        // ii. Call the Call internal method of callback with T as
        // the this value and argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
        callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }
    // 8. return undefined
  };
}
```

Plus this to use with html elements:

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
```

Voila!

Comment: Haha! I think it was my first question on SO. I totally forgot about it. It seems I was already thinking about functional programming event though didn't know the name yet :) Thanks for reminding me and +1 for the `NodeList` / `HTMLCollection` idea.